# Sentiment analysis started returning errors for most of the documents

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I've been using the sentiment analysis service for quite some time, but a few days ago it started returning a non-empty list of errors regarding the documents I send, even though it also returns results for them:

```
%{"documents" => 
     [..., %{"id" => "35", "score" => 0.5}, ...], 
  "errors" => 
     [..., %{"id" => "35", "message" => "Truncated input to first 100 tokens during analysis."}, ...]
}
```

Did anything change recently? Does this mean the documents have been truncated to 100 chars or words? These are tweets that I am processing so they are already restricted in char length.

Is there documentation regarding all the different errors that can be returned regarding a document and the reason for it?

Comment: The docs  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-sentiment-analysis#preparation) say that the text must be less than 5k characters. Maybe you can share a sample document you're using?

Comment: I'm processing tweets, so a sample would be:
"‘Travis Strikes Again’ Director Suda 51 Interview | Digital Trends xxxxx/Fctea7zGxp", or "No More Heroes: Travis Strikes Again Officially Revealed for Nintendo Switch - IGN\nXxxxco/ZHOQZo7qoX xxxxx/WcBgVn77Y1".

It's highly unlikely that a tweet could have 5k characters, but I'll try to add more logging to catch the specific documents that get that error. Today I haven't received those errors yet.

Comment: Ah, sounds like a temporary error on their end then

Comment: Hey @AndréCruz, Did you ever figure out what was the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was too long ago, can't remember.